# Wordpress site showing installation page after migration

Tags: php, wordpress, migration, wordpress-theming

I want to migrate wordpress (change hosting) and for this first of all i moved all files and folder to new hosting panel and change base url in wordpress,but after migration whenever i refresh home page then its showing installation of wordpress(fresh wordpress installation) so how can fix this issue ? where i am wrong ? here is my .htaccess file

## BEGIN WordPress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Please check database name ,is it uppercase? or it is same

Comment: @PawanThakur: its same

Comment: Check wp_config table's prefix

Comment: @PawanThakur: i changed with old prefix (wpgo) but still not working

Comment: did you match uername, password and db name with current db?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

you have 5 steps to do it.

1. step 1: move your files to new host
2. step 2: export your database from your prev hosting.
3. step 3: create new data base in your new hosting panel.
4. step 4: import your exported data base to your new data base in your
   new hosting.
5. step 5: edit your wp-config.php and with your new data base
   information (like data base name , data base user and user password)